# Pass a variable from UIHostingController to SWIFTUI view

Tags: swiftui, uikit

I have a storyboard app and now starting with SwiftUI views in my existing app. I have a API calls that populates variables eg: name, surname, email and mobile.

How do I pass the UIKit variable in my UIHostingController to display in SwiftUI view?

My storyboard UIKit file:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
class UserDashboardHostVC: UIViewController {
    
    var name = String()
    var surname = String()
    var email = String()
    var mobile = String()
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        getAPIdata() 
        //this populates the above 4 variables.    
        
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: UserDashboard())
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addChild(controller)
        self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

My SwiftUI view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserDashboard: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{

           Text(name)
           Spacer()
           Text(surname)
           Spacer()
           Text(email)
           Spacer()
           Text(mobile)
           Spacer()
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your UserDashboard view file should be showing you compiler messages that it cannot find name, surname, email and mobile in scope. Start by defining these within the view, but outside it's body. let name: String, let surname: String... etc.

Then, once you've done this, the compiler will throw up an error where you've instantiated an instance of UserDashboard within your UserDashboardHostVC saying that it doesn't have the correct initialisers. Fix this, and you should be sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move those properties from controller into standalone view model class and pass instance of that class into SwiftUI view, like shown below.

*Also you can pass same model into `getAPI` function to update model's properties. (Note: properties must be updated on main queue to refresh SwiftUI view!)

```
class UserDashboardModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = String()
    @Published var surname = String()
    @Published var email = String()
    @Published var mobile = String()
}

class UserDashboardHostVC: UIViewController {

    var model = UserDashboardModel()      // << here owner !!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getAPIdata()             // << can be injected here
        //this populates the above 4 variables.

        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: UserDashboard(model: self.model))     // << here !!
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addChild(controller)
        self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}

struct UserDashboard: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: UserDashboardModel    // << here !!

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{

           Text(model.name)
           Spacer()
           Text(model.surname)
           Spacer()
           Text(model.email)
           Spacer()
           Text(model.mobile)
           Spacer()
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Just a question on PreviewProvider, it ask for the model and added "static var previews: some View {
        UserDashboard(model: self.model)
    }" but I get an error "Type 'UserDashboard_Previews' has no member 'model'". Can this be resolved?

Comment: You can see example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319045/12299030 or here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66462161/12299030.